# How storing array values in different columns of table using php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Here is the piece of code so far I've tried:

```
$month = array('red','green','red');
$values = array();
foreach($month as $dataset)
{
   $values[] = ($dataset);
}

$columns = implode(", ",array_keys($values));
$escaped_values = array_values($values);
$valu  = implode(", ", $escaped_values);

$sql = "INSERT INTO abc (col1,col2,col3) VALUES ('$valu');";
```

Here is the output:

> Error: INSERT INTO abc (col1,col2,col3) VALUES ('red, green, red');
>   Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

What I am trying to do is to store values in the array where the value of the array may vary depending upon the value the user gave, and then store it in different columns. For example, if the total columns are 3 and array value is 2 then store values in col1 and col2 and null value in col3.

Comment: Each value has to be enclosed in single quotes

Comment: Thanks for upvote. Feel free to accept this as answer if the solution addressed your concern.

Comment: just add `'` -> `$values[] = "'{$dataset}'";` and remove the `'` in `$sql`

Comment: You should be using prepared statements and bind variables rather than trying to get something inherently insecure to work.

Comment: Do you want a correct answer? Showing use of prepared queries or the one which is a quick fix thats open to SQL injection like the answers below?

Comment: @kip thanks its finally working now!!! :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the Code after making it work properly

```
$month = array('red','green','red');
$values = array();
foreach($month as $dataset)
{
  $values[] = "'{$dataset}'";
}

$columns = implode(", ",array_keys($values));
$escaped_values = array_values($values);
$valu  = implode(", ", $escaped_values);

$sql = "INSERT INTO abc (col1,col2,col3) VALUES ($valu);";
```

Answer (score 1):

With the single quotes around the whole string `'red, green, red'` that is the value for `col1` only.

It should look more like this 'red','green','red'.

So quick fix is this `$valu  = implode("','", $escaped_values);`

Added a single quotes inside your implode.

The outside quotes will be captured in the final statement as detailied in the problem above:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO abc (col1,col2,col3) VALUES ('$valu');";
```

Comment: @kip after passing `$valu` to query text everything will be fine.

Comment: Yes that is correct but the code has the final piece with the outside qoutes in this statement: `$sql = "INSERT INTO abc (col1,col2,col3) VALUES ('$valu');";`

Comment: @mcv I forget the query text, sorry

Comment: @kip no worries. it's easy to overlook things when I didn't include it. So I added it to ensure that there was no confusion. :)

Answer (score 0):

The values are into the single quote. Please check below example.

```
INSERT INTO abc (col1,col2,col3) VALUES ('red', 'green', 'red');
```

Comment: value will be pass in an array

Comment: @Zohaib Yes correct, I have just given you example so you can understand the issue.

Comment: i knew the problem but didn't knew how to solve it @kip gave the correct solution problem was here $values[] = "'{$dataset}'";

Answer (score 0):

No one else seems to have addressed the actual issue.

> What I am trying to do is to store values in the array where the value
>   of the array may vary depending upon the value the user gave, and then
>   store it in different columns. For example, if the total columns are 3
>   and array value is 2 then store values in col1 and col2 and null value
>   in col3.

So if the values come in as an array at different lengths, and you want to insert as null or limit to the max length of the columns then you can do it like the following.

Ideally, you want to produce an array which looks like:

```
$data = [
    'col1' => 'red',
    'col2' => 'green',
    'col3' => null
];
```

To do that without any looping define the database columns, then create an array of the same length of null values, then slice the input array to the same length and merge, this will produce an array like above.

```
<?php
$columns = [
    'col1',
    'col2',
    'col3',
];
$month = [
    'red',
    'green'
];

$data = array_combine(
    $columns, 
    array_slice($month, 0, count($columns))+array_fill(0, count($columns), null)
);
```

Now you simply need to implode the array into your query, using `?` for placeholders for the prepared query.

```
$sql = '
INSERT INTO abc (
    '.implode(', ', array_keys($data)).'
) VALUES (
    '.implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($data), '?')).'
)';
```

Will produce:

```
INSERT INTO abc (
    col1, col2, col3
) VALUES (
    ?, ?, ?
)
```

Then just do your query, for example:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($data);
```

Simple clean and safe.